# Is there an easy way to add a "--Select--" option to a DataBound DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have a DataBound DropDownList that is loading fine, but i'd like to insert another item that says "--Select--" or something instead of having the first DataBound item automatically display.

Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to manually add a dummy item?

Here is my code:

```
            MyContext fc = new MyContext ();
            ddl.DataSource = fc.SomeTable;
            ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do the databind do:

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, "---Select---");
```

This will add it as the first item in the list.

Alternatively, you can add a new [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) instead of a string, so you can have an actual value instead of a string as drop down list value.

So you can do something like:

```
ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", Guid.Empty.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, add a default item in the markup and set the "AppendDataBoundItems" property to true.

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">

       <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="---Please Select---"></asp:ListItem>

   </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: This will be gone after the DataBind would it not?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: No, because AppendDataBoundItems="true"